# Autocomplete input box that allows alternate spellings of options

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I've been trying to implement the Jquery autocomplete box in my web application, but it doesn't have a certain functionality that I really need. I'm looking to be able to type multiple spellings of an option, but have them return only the main option.

Example: Autocomplete box of all the states: Alabama, Alaska, Arizona...

I want to be able to type in "AK" and have Alaska still come up or "VA" and still have Virginia come up. Currently with autocomplete, both of these would not show but I feel there should be a way to set alternate spellings that still return.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: How are you storing the state list?  Abbreviation list?

Answer (score 0):

Try Object.keys / Object.hasOwnProperty()

```
var getStates(userInput){

var states = [{AK: Alaska}, {IA: Iowa}] //etc.
var prop = Object.keys(userInput);

for (var i in states){
  if (states[i].hasOwnProperty(prop) === true){
    return states[i];
  }
}

}
```